# Can Anyone recommend a well design open source project with Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Can Anyone recommend a well design open source project with Entity Framework? I had some tastes about the Entity Framework 4, but I would love to know how people use this framework in some large projects.

Many thanks.

Daoming

Comment: I don't think that you will find one. All well designed ones uses nhibernate ;)

Answer (score 2):

While not large, you could check out the [All-In-One Code Framework](http://cfx.codeplex.com/) samples.  I think there are at least a few examples of the Entity Framework in there.  One specific example is:

[How to work with table relationships and entity inheritances in ADO.NET Entity Data Model](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977997)

> This code sample includes a step-by-step guide about how to work with Entity Data Model in various ways, including One-to-Many association, Many-to-Many association, One-to-One association, table merging, table splitting, Table-per-Hierarchy inheritance, and Table-per-Type inheritance.

**EDIT:**

They just added another sample:

> **CSEFCodeOnly, VBEFCodeOnly**
>
> These two samples illustrate how to
>   use one of the EF4 new features, Code
>   Only, to create the EDM metadata and
>   the corresponding .edmx file with POCO
>   entity classes during runtime.  They
>   also demonstrate some basic insert and
>   query operations to test the EDM
>   metadata generated by Code Only.

Answer (score 2):

So far the best I've found is 
http://www.nopcommerce.com/ - since  1.70 (July 7, 2010) they have been using Entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

See http://kigg.codeplex.com/
Highly recommended for an ALT.NET style of doing Entity Framework.

It shows a way of abstracting yourself from the ORM even.

A different project with similar architecture: 
http://shrinkr.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the product called Virto Commerce. The site is http://virtocommerce.com. It is an open source project based on Entity Framework using Repository and Unit Of Work pattern. The source code is https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-community.

Comment: You should at least disclosure your affiliate with virtocommerce.com.

Comment: Yes, I'm an architect of Virto Commerce, but the question was on example of using Entity Framework, which is what I'm happy to share with everyone via open source. I'm not discussing that VC is better than anything or comparign it, so I don't see the point of disclosure. Also clicking on my profile will show my association.

Comment: I'm not going to argue, it's your decision, I just tried to prevent you from getting in trouble over time. [Avoid overt self-promotion.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

It's 2014. The answer to the question is still no.

The reason is not obvious, I hope I can explain.  Most typical open source project become successful because they are extensible, and thus allow the community around it to grow.  Extensible means extending Entities and thus the database in some way for each plugin. However, EF only supports one version of an entity graph, and so you can't say, add a plugin, and then upgrade the original database.  It'll break migration.  And thus people don't use EF in OS projects.

You can see people are struggling to create plugins in nopcommerce because of this.  Any plugin that needs additional properties on an object requires code changes in the core.  Essentially, any deployment of nopcommerce that has a plugin, is a fork of the project.  The end user ends up becoming the developer because they now have to do source code control, merges, etc.  A person selling things online doesn't have that kind of skill. They just want to install plugin, and go.  So... no, EF is terrible for open source projects.  For big monolithic projects, it's great though.

Comment: Don't think that is a correct statement. True that EF can only support one graph but that shouldn't make it impossible to create plugins. The tyicaly extension should be able to add or override existing functionality but modifying existing entities is not always a requirement. It really depends on higher level extensibility support and is not a limitation imposed by EF.

Comment: If it really depends on some 'higher level' magic, nopcommerce sure hasn't found it yet.  And they are already using things like IoC and MEF.  There is no fix right now because migrations in EF is snapshot based.  In fact, there's even a document from microsoft about it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx  Note that the article demonstrates the issue in just one class, but the problem also applies when the changes are in different classes.  Search for "entity framework code first migration team environment"

Comment: Yes, you can't use Migrations for plugin customizations. Application has to be designed to support extensibility while EF will support upgrading/migrating those plugins to the newer version (by vendor). It shouldn't be used for customization for a particular business need.

Comment: In this [article](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Extending+Members+domain+types) described how to make pluggable  extension for EF persistent infrastructure. And I sure that it is not the task of EF be extensible, it's already all have for it.